# Most Powerful test for Gumbel distribution

Tags: statistics, hypothesis-testing

A single observation obtained from Gumbel distribution has pdf 
$f(x)$ = $e^{-(x-a) - e^{-(x-a)}}$.

Show that most powerful test for $H_0$: $a=0$ vs. $H_A$ : $a= a_1$ where $a_1 > 0$ has rejection region RR = ${x>c}$ where $c$ is constant.

I don't understand what question asking. I did likelihood test and $$\frac{L(\theta_o)}{L(\theta_a)} = \frac {e^{-x-e^{-x}}} {e^{-(x-{a_1})-e^{-(x-{a_1})}}}$$ = $$ e^{(e^a - 1)(e^{-x})-a} $$

But there is no range for x or alpha given, so what is next step?

Comment: I assume you are familiar with the Neyman-Pearson lemma? This Lemma indicates the rejection region is defined as
$$\left\{x : \frac{L(x \ | \ \theta_0)}{L(x \ | \ \theta_a)} \geq k \right\}.$$
This will allow you to find the required critical value $c$. Note that $c$ will be in function of $k$ (which you do not know). This value can be found using the type I-error.

Comment: How do you find type 1 error though? Probability is not given and this is not binomial

Comment: Type one error is the probability to reject $H_0$ assumed that $H_0$ is true (hence assuming $a=0$). Note that this probability is equal to the significance level $\alpha$ (that is how it is defined). You therefore have $$\mathbb{P}(X>c \ | \ H_0) = \alpha.$$

Comment: So $\alpha$ = P[X > c|a=0]. But $\alpha$ is not given, so how to solve?

Comment: In most cases $\alpha$ is given. Common choices are $\alpha = 5\%$ and $\alpha = 1 \%$. This the significance level for the hypothesis test.

Comment: If 0.05 = P[X > c|a=0] , how to solve without c?

Comment: I believe the Question was originally about the *power* of a statistical test, for a definition of which, [see here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Statistical_power).